# Moongose - how to customize a field in a scheme ? string and array in the same field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know how I can customize a field where you can use an array and string
eg:

```
var PostingSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    images: Array,
    categorie: Array,
    ubication:[{ type: Number, ref: 'Place'}],
    agg:[{
    agg   :{ type: String, ref: 'Agg' },
    value : String,
    make  :[{ type: Number, ref: 'Make'}]
  }]
});
```

In the field `agg` value, I have a problem that can sometimes be of type string and sometimes can be of type array , should be of the array type I populate it with another scheme. How can I do that?

I made a field called `"value ->string"` and a `"make->array"` to do if there is a better way?

Comment: Do you mean `agg` type inside `agg` can be both `String` and `Array`? If it is, you should use as `type: Array` instead of string.

Comment: the agg.value field can be both (array , string)
    eg:
     agg : {
     value: "automatic"
    }
or  
     agg : {
     value: [ 1,2,3,4,5 ] // ref another eschema and needs to be populated
    }   @Khay